# How to read from a specific character onwards within a file?

Tags: c, file, stream, hex

I've a file `RTCM3.bin`. When I convert this file into hexadecimal characters, I can see its content. For example:
`0x3A, 0x00, 0x04, 0x10, 0xD3, 0x00, 0x95, 0x3E, 0xC0, 0x01, 0x49, 0x66, 0xA6, 0x42, 0x90, 0x09, 0x2E, 0x0D, 0x8E, 0x00, 0x30, 0x86, 0x14, 0x68, 0x70` etc. etc.

The problem is that this characters are passed to a function:

```
FILE *p;
p = fopen("./RTCM3.bin", "r");
int y = fgetc(p);
printf("First character in input to input_rtcm3f: %d\n", y); 
int x  = input_rtcm3f(&rtcm, p);
printf("Return value of input_rtcm3f: %d\n", x);
```

Anyway, I need to provide in input to the `input_rtcm3` function only the characters from 0xD3 onwards. In this case:

```
`0xD3, 0x00, 0x95, 0x3E, 0xC0, 0x01, 0x49` etc. etc.
```

How can I do it? `y` is the integer value of 0xD3, that is 211. So, `y` should be 211 I think.

Comment: Read the file in a loop until you get `0xd3`. Then start calling `input_rtcm3f()` with the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fseek` is what you are looking for:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm

With `fseek` you can move the file pointer to the correct position if you know the offset.

Otherwise you would have to loop to the correct character while consuming from the stream with `fgetc`.

Comment: No. The file has been opened in text mode: `p = fopen("./RTCM3.bin", "r");` [`fseek()` doesn't work that way for text streams](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p4): "For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET."

Comment: I suggest that you use [this reference for the function `fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) instead. In particular, you may want to pay close attention to this parapraph of the referenced documentation: "If the stream is open in text mode, the only supported values for offset are zero (which works with any origin) and a value returned by an earlier call to ftell on a stream associated with the same file (which only works with origin of SEEK_SET)."

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have two options to solve this problem:

1. Read all bytes with `fgetc` in a loop, until you encounter the byte with the value `0xD3`.
2. If you know the offset of the byte with the value `0xD3`, jump directly to that offset using the function [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek).

However, option #2 has the following problem:

In ISO C, calling [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) with the mode argument `"r"` will open the file in text mode. In that mode, you are only allowed to pass offset values previously returned by the function [`ftell`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell). You cannot simply pass the offset value `4`.

However, in your case, since the input file seems to be a binary file, it would probably be better to open the file in binary mode instead of text mode, by passing `"rb"` as the mode argument to `fopen`. That way, you can simply pass the offset `4` to `fseek`.

Note that some operating systems such as Linux do not distinguish between text mode and binary mode. When using such operating systems, you can simply pass the offset `4` to `fseek`, even if you opened the file with the mode `"r"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the offset (e.g.: you're skipping a standard header and such) then you should use `fseek` to move the pointer in the file to the right position.

If you don't know the offset then you'll have to find it yourself - read the file until you get to the place you want in a loop, and then call the function once you're there (you may need to use `fseek` to move back one position).

Comment: According to [§7.21.9.2 ¶4 of the ISO C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p4), calling `fseek` with the non-zero offset will invoke undefined behavior for a stream opened in text mode, unless that offset was obtained from a previous call to `ftell`. Note that OP is opening the file in text mode, not binary mode. Therefore, your solution is not portable; it is only guaranteed to work on platforms that do not distinguish between text mode and binary mode (such as Linux). On the other hand, OP should probably be opening the file in binary mode anyway.